# bash scripting - what does "ls .." (ls with double dot) do?

Tags: bash, ls

My homework asked me to find what `ls ..` does.

I tried to search the internet but I couldn't find any answer to the question.

Does someone know what this command does?

Comment: `..` is the parent directory

Comment: `.` and `..` have special meaning here, `.` means current directory whereas `..` means one level up. so doing `ls ..` means listing the content of parent directory. You should delete this question. if your quesry is answered.

Comment: I can imagine googling for `..` is difficult.

Comment: yea google disable special characters :(

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`..` is an entry in the current directory that refers to the parent of the current directory. It's not a special convention used just by `ls`. For example:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ pwd
/usr/bin
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/usr
$ [ -d .. ] && echo "It's a directory"
It's a directory
$ stat ..
<output specific to your installed version of stat>
```